# How to encrypt/decrypt text using a X509Certificate & AES-256 algorithm

Tags: c#, encryption, x509certificate2

I have a X509 certificate that I would like to use to encrypt/decrypt password.  However, I can only use AES-256 algorithm.

Everything I have found on the internet suggests to use RSACryptoServiceProvider, but that does not do AES-256 encryption.

I don't know a lot about encryption so some basic code examples would help a lot.

Comment: I would start from [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) and specify key size. Also there is a code sample in [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx) that does AES256

Answer (score 5):

AES is a symmetric-key algorithm, meaning the same key is used for both encrypting and decrypting the data.

RSA is a asymmtric-key algorithm.  The key in the public certificate is used for encrypting.  A private key is then used for decrypting.

RSA cryptographic operations are time consuming.  Normal practice is to generate a random AES key, encrypt the key with RSA and then encrypt the plain text with AES.

See [how to use RSA to encrypt files (huge data) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199058/how-to-use-rsa-to-encrypt-files-huge-data-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do encryption yourself, it's easy to get wrong even if you know what you are doing. Use a high level library. I've ported [Kecyzar in C#](http://jbtule.github.com/keyczar-dotnet/) for this reason.