# How to create digital signature(RSA) of file's checksum?

Tags: c#, rsa, digital-signature, sha256

Welcome!
My job is to implement digital signature. I've read everything about creating public and private key but I'm stuck with this silly thing. 
How do I encrypt this checksum(SHA256) using RSA algorithm? I mean part: c(m) = m ^ e mod n. Should I convert this checksum(which is HEX?) to int, so that then I can compute ^e mod n?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on your own? Or are you using the built in RSA encryption provider? [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199058/how-to-use-rsa-to-encrypt-files-huge-data-in-c-sharp)

Comment: My aim is to implement it on my own way, avoiding built-in or external libraries.

Comment: Why? Homework? Reimplementing security is almost guaranteed to be a quagmire of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You don't encrypt the checksum but sign it. If you use C#, take a look at RSACryptoServiceProvider class, in particular in MSDN's [Cryptographic Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk8wx38z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) section which contains detailed description of the process.

However it seems that you are reinventing the wheel and going too low-level. Maybe higher-level libraries like BouncyCastle or free [CryptoBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-cryptobb.php) package of our SecureBlackbox will be easier to use.